# Drop down according to Location - gravity forms

Tags: forms, input, gravity

Does any of you know if it is possible to get different dropdown field according to the location you are in?

Preferably in Gravity Forms.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, you didn't really provide enough information to provide much guidance.

A general approach is to have an array for each set of choices you want. These can either be hard coded or you can pull them dynamically from a database depending on how many there are and whether they change.

Here's a link to the Gravity Forms support site with info on [how to dynamically populate the drop-down](https://docs.gravityforms.com/dynamically-populating-drop-down-fields/).

You could have a dropdown before the one you mention that determines which set of data to use to populate your main dropdown.